# React Redux will not reset store of some component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

I have a weird problem with my redux store:
I can set it from within my app, but i want to reset it to the components initialState on logout.
Nothing seems to be working on this specific componet. In other components the root reducer method works. It is a relatively big project, but I am very certain, that my components logic is the same as the working components.

The reducer looks something like this:

```js
const initialState = {
    myList: [
        {
          key: 'ListKey1',
          formats: [],
          selectedFormat: '',
          printer: {},
        },
        {
          key: 'ListKey2',
          active: false,
          formats: [],
          selectedFormat: '',
          printer: {},
        },
        {
          key: 'ListKey3',
          active: false,
          formats: [],
          selectedFormat: '',
          printer: {},
        },
      ],
};


export default function myReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
    ...
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I tried the rootReducer Method:

```js
const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'LOGOUT') {
      return appReducer(undefined, action);
    }

    return appReducer(state, action);
  };
```

Which doesnt seem to touch the initialState whatsoever.

What i have also tried it the 'old fashioned' way, by catching the logout case in the reducer.
Which also doesn't do anything.

```js
    ...
    case 'LOGOUT':
        return initialState;
    default:
        return state;
    ...
```

When I replace initialState with an empty array, it works/overwrites the state.

```js
    ...
    case 'LOGOUT':
        return [];
    default:
        return state;
    ...
```

but this is of course not woking for my app

Maybe anyone here can help, you are my last resort, googling didn't help much.
Cheers! :D

## Update:

Here is my `mapStateToProps`

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  selectedList: state.settings.myList,
});
```

Comment: Unless you absolutely need Redux, I recommend just using React hooks with a global store such as Reactn.  Much less code and less classes.

Comment: it is sadly not up to me, and we are also using sagas, so it might be limiting the choice.

Comment: Concise code is not the recommendation not to use Redux imo. I wouldn't spread that advice lightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

looking closely at [Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns)
and listening to what others said, I realized that my setters for the selectedList might be mutating the state:

```
handleFormatSelect = (format, index) => {
    const { myList, updateMyList} = this.props;
    let tmpList = myList;     //This is not creating a new instance, but a reference
    tmpList [index].selectedFormat = format;
    updateMyList(tmpPrintersList);
  };
```

I also changed the myList object, so I don't have to access nested objects. (it's a pita, looking at the redux wiki)

```
  ...
  ListKey1: {
    key: 'ListKey1',
    formats: [],
    selectedFormat: '',
    printer: {},
  },
  ListKey2: {
    key: 'ListKey2',
    active: false,
    formats: [],
    selectedFormat: '',
    printer: {},
  },
  ListKey3: {
    key: 'ListKey3',
    active: false,
    formats: [],
    selectedFormat: '',
    printer: {},
  },
  ...
```

Finally, I also updated the setting functions to not mutate state:

```
  handleFormatSelect = (format, listKey) => {
    const tmpKey = Object.assign({}, listKey);
    tmpKey.selectedFormat = format;
    this.updateMyList(tmpKey);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Components will rerender only if you have different reference for your data. e.g. your initial value will be set in the beginning and then if you set store value to initial value again which is same object, components will not get rerendered. You just need to update the reference.

```
case 'LOGOUT':
   return { myList: [...initialState.myList ] };
default:
   return state;
```

Comment: That's inexact. The `return initialState` should re-render the view.

Comment: @Freez No, if current store state is same as initialState, it will not rerender

Comment: If the current store state is equal is the same that initial state why would be render again the view?

Comment: @Freez That's what I am saying. It will not rerender

Comment: it is not the same, otherwise it wouldn't matter, i want it empty, but my values remain inside

Comment: Thank you @A.Benjamins. Check your reducer implementation, maybe you mutate `initialState` at some point, so React/Redux cannot make the diff.

Comment: I created a second initialState, with i tried returning in this case, to see if i mutated the variable, but it didnt clear the state.

Comment: @A.Benjamins In your mapStateToProps, do you try to bind `myReducer.myList` to a props (not myReducer, but directly the `myList` field)

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz What I mean is that your code example doesn't make sense, we agree that if the previous state === next state the view will not be re-rendered. 
But if previous state !== next state with next state === initialState, it should re-render.

Comment: @A.Benjamins Can you reproduce your issue here https://codesandbox.io/s/oj7px08qy9

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-35qh0 I added an action RESET, with `return initialState` inside the reducer, and the UI is re-rendered.

Comment: I can't really reproduce this in the sandbox, because my code follows the 'normal' flow of your examples. It should work :8 I will update the question with my `mapstateToProps`